# Moving from elementary OS to Xubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10, xubuntu, backup, migration

One of my Pcs is dualbooted between elementary os luna running on kernel 3.11 and xubuntu 3.10.

Elementary os is no longer booting correctly, it's booting into tty. I am unable to connect to the internet from there.

What I want to do is to, somehow, go to my Xubuntu partition, backup everything that I have on elementary os, remove elementary os, install (or reinstall) Xubuntu on the whole hard disk, and reinstall the backup.

I can reinstall Xubuntu without worrying about it, I have nothing there. But on Elementary OS, I have many apps installed from software center, and spotify and ruby and nodejs and django and my virtualenvs.

Is it possible to move all these to Xubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

Since elementary os luna stems from ubuntu 12.04 LTS it is two releases behind your xubuntu 13.10 and thus this is not likely to succeed:

```
you@eos:~# dpkg --get-selections > /some/share/selections.txt
```

```
you@xubuntu:~# cat /some/share/selections.txt | dpkg --set-selections
```

This will also pick packages that are only in Luna, so you must edit the selections.txt before applying it on xubuntu.

However, the two systems are similar enough to repair elementary as root from xubuntu:

```
root@xubuntu:~# mkdir -p /tmp/eos
root@xubuntu:~# mount -t auto /dev/disk/by-label/yourEosPartitionLabel /tmp/eos
root@xubuntu:~# mount --bind /dev /tmp/eos/dev
root@xubuntu:~# mount --bind /proc /tmp/eos/proc
root@xubuntu:~# chroot /tmp/eos
# now we are in a running eos with internet access from xubuntu
root@eos:~# apt-get install -f linux-image-generic
# plus other fixes you may try
root@eos:~# exit
root@xubuntu:~# umount /tmp/eos/dev
root@xubuntu:~# umount /tmp/eos/proc
```

This would install the old generic 12.04 kernel that is more likely to boot.